# How do I put multiple rows of a MySQL database into a multidimensional array (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am working on a system where a query checks the database for records matching multiple ids and puts each row into it's own array. So far I only got the last row to echo out in it's own array. Here is the query code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE senderid IN ($senderids) ORDER BY messageid DESC";
$resource = mysql_query($query, $database);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
foreach($result as $result1)
    {
    print_r($result1);
    echo '<br>';
    }
```

This is what echos in the browser:

```
2
2
1
1
TEST MSG 2
TEST MSG 2
2014_09_13_01:29:59
2014_09_13_01:29:59
```

This is what should echo:

```
Array ([messageid] => 1 [senderid] => 1 [message] => test message [date] => 2014_09_13_01:01:09)
Array ([messageid] => 2 [senderid] => 1 [message] => TEST MSG 2 [date] => 2014_09_13_01:29:59)
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: just for fyi....your code is open for sql injection...search for mysqli_ or PDO queries.

Comment: @NoobEditor The $senderid variable is escaped using mysql_real_escape_string earlier in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` does not return the whole result set, just the row at the current cursor. Your code isn't moving the mysql cursor; to do that, your code should be:

```
$resource = mysql_query($query, $database);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resource)){
  print_r($row);
  echo '<br />';
}
```

Also, for the desired output you posted, you should use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead as it will be a hash with column names instead of an indexed array

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE senderid IN ($senderids) ORDER BY messageid DESC";
$resource = mysql_query($query, $database);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resource))
{
print_r($result);    // OR $array[] = $result; and print $array outside the while loop 
}
```